# Deleting few selected characters from a file in vi/vim editor

Tags: vim, command, vi

Below is the command to delete first `N` characters in vi:

```
:%s/^.\{N}//g
```

However, I don't understand the meaning of `^.\{N}`; can anyone explain the meaning of *each character by character*?
How to extend this command to delete in-between characters from lines ?

> **e.g.** deleting 4th to 50th characters from given range of lines

Comment: As an addendum to the other answers, you can specify the range of lines at the beginning of the command. For the whole file the % in `:%s` is used. For example, to execute a substitute on lines 7 through 47 you could use `:7,47s` and then the rest of the command. For more information see `:help :range`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match specific columns with **[`\%c`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%2f%5c%25c)** or **[`\%v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%2f%5c%25v)**

Delete 4th to 50th column:

```
 :%s/\%4c.\{-}\(\ze\%50c\|$\)//
```

To only delete IFF there is a 50th column:

```
 :%s/\%4c.\{-}\ze\%50c//
```

To use virtual columns (e.g. handy if you use tab stops):

```
 :%s/\%4v.\{-}\ze\%50v//
```

Oh,

- `.\{-}` is a non-greedy match of zero or more characters.
- `\ze` is the *end-of-match* directive, this stops the match at column 50

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex part explanation

`^` is the start-of-the-line anchor.

`.` matched any character.

`N` indicates the number of characters the previous token will be matched

`{}` is used to group the count. For example you can use it as `{1, 9}`

So it says, `From the beginning of the line, match N characters` and the rest is VIM stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is the start-of-line anchor; `.` is the universal match, `{N}` repeats the previous match N times.

To delete the 4th to 50th character, use `:%s/^\(.\{4}\).\{46}/\1/g`.

However, it's probably easier to use rectangular selection mode: from normal mode, move to the start location, then hit `Ctrl+V` and you can create a rectangular selection by moving the cursor.